# How to change the font-color of price data when it is greater than 20?

Tags: javascript, html, css

im trying to inject a js on google optimize for this [page](https://assetstore.unity.com/?category=2d)

trying to make all values over £20 color red

```
var eArr = document.getElementsByClassName("mErEH _223RA")
for(i=0;i<eArr["length"];i++){
  if (eArr[i].innerHTML > 20)
    eArr[i].style.color = "#ff0000";
}
```

Cant get this working, im not sure if im capturing the correct class with "mErEH _223RA"

```
<div class="mErEH _223RA" data-reactid="207">€49.89</div>
```

```
var eArr = document.getElementsByClassName("mErEH _223RA")
for(i=0;i<eArr["length"];i++){
  if (eArr[i].innerHTML > 20)
    eArr[i].style.color = "#ff0000";
}
```

Comment: Welcome! That's two separate classes. You would only need one of those to select the data - but that class name may be autogenerated and changed every page load.

Comment: ah i didnt think about the possibility of it changing. Ideally i would want it to work on loading and filter change. Is my code not reasonable anymore then?

Comment: Looks like the class stays the same, as I'm getting the same. Pick one of the classes `mErEH` or `_223RA` and try that.